# How to get the location of a web request?

Tags: geolocation

What's the best way to get the location (to a country level) of where a web request is coming from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 ways, generally speaking:

- Use GeoIP or some similar database or service which maps IPs to physical locations
- Use the [W3C geolocation api](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/) (supported by newer browsers only)
- Google gears geolocation

Comment: +1 for the new geolocation api. It can be much more precise, but requires a newish browser and user permission (whereas IP to location can be run on any data source, even access logs).

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch IP from header and from IP get location.

for Java Web App.

You can put a Filter to intercept each request and

```
  request.getRemoteAddr();// //will return you
```

then there are lots of service available to perform resolution from IP to map to its location

Comment: Yup, country-scale IP geolocation is more or less accurate. Any more precise, and you'll run into problems (which mostly means "those pesky users with their mobile connections, always running around" nowadays).